# PHP Carbon: How to get diffInDays if hours difference is less than 24 hours?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm having 2 different dates with less than 24 hours difference. When I try to get difference in days I get `0`:

```php
$end => 2022-09-07 02:20:47  
$now => 2022-09-06 16:00:00 

$diffDays = $end->diffInDays($now, false); // return 0
$diffDays = $now->diffInDays($end, false); // return 0
```

How to make detect that this is another day and should return `diffInDays` as `1` not `0`.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For this use case, I would take both dates to the start/end of the day and then get diff in days. `$end->startOfDay()->diffInDays($now->startOfDay())` Because, you are counting the days as soon as the next day starts, regardless of the hour difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diffInHours() < 24`, and you can also mix it with `diffInMinutes < 60`. If it's either of those, then return `1`. However, I would suggest dropping the `absolute = false` flag for doing that, as negative numbers will always hit those checks.

```php
$end = Carbon::parse('2022-09-07 02:20:47');
$now = Carbon::parse('2022-09-06 16:00:00');

// These will return 10
$diffHours = $end->diffInHours($now);
$diffHours = $now->diffInHours($end);

// These return 620
$diffMinutes = $end->diffInMinutes($now);
$diffMinutes = $now->diffInMinutes($end);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because method signature looks like this:

```php
public function diffInDays(Carbon $dt = null, $abs = true)
{
    $dt = $dt ?: static::now($this->getTimezone());

    return (int) $this->diff($dt, $abs)->format('%r%a');
}
```

so it will round it to lower (0) if under 24 hours.

Maybe you want try `floatDiffInDays` instead to see different in decimal?
See sample below,

```php
echo Carbon::parse('2000-01-01 12:00')->floatDiffInDays('2000-02-11 06:00');     // 40.75
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the function `startOfDay()` as mentioned by user [@user3532758](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625348/php-carbon-how-to-get-diffindays-if-hours-difference-is-less-than-24-hours#comment130015031_73625348).

With the only important difference, that I used `copy()` or `clone()` to prevent the instance from being mutated.

```php
$end = Carbon::parse('2022-09-07 02:20:47');
$now = Carbon::parse('2022-09-06 16:00:00');

$diffCalendarDays1 = $end->clone()->startOfDay()->diffInDays($now); // return 1
$diffCalendarDays2 = $now->clone()->startOfDay()->diffInDays($end); // return 1
```